# Creating two different rest api with optional values

Tags: rest

I am just new to rest api and need to create two api. both of them use post.

1) First one takes 2 parameters inside of the body

```
url is : /myapp/resources
```

2) Second one is doing the same function as the first one does but it needs 2 optional parameter. I thought using path or request param but as the parameters are optional it will be confusing when there is no paramaters. So there will be conflict with the first api.

```
/myapp/resources?param1=xx&param2=xx ==> what if there is no parameter
/myapp/resources/param1/{xxx}/param2/{yyy} ==> so still what if there is no param:
```

So what is the best way to define second api without causing a conflict with the first api when optional parameters are not passed.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going with the first approach (*query params*) so:
`/myapp/resources?param1=xx&param2=xx`

The reason being - in this case you can define or extend the logic of just one endpoint, the `/myapp/resources`, that is going to verify if parameters exist and react accordingly.

With the second approach (*path params*), you would have to most likely define two (or more) separate endpoints (like `/myapp/resources/`, `/myapp/resources/param1/{param1}` and `/myapp/resources/param1/{param1}/param2/{param2}`

Comment: @user1474111 Is anything not clear in the answer or anything still remains unanswered for you? :)